# Angular 6 Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings

Tags: angular

I migrated the old angular project to angular

When run the project is compiling successfully but in the console it's showing below error.

> Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
>       at assertArrayOfStrings (compiler.js:2181)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata
>   (compiler.js:10373)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata

Angular.json

```
"styles": [
    {
    "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
    },
    "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [],
```

Component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
```

Where i am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to pass array of strings to styles, and also styles doesn't support file urls.

Comment: i updated my question with component.ts decorater

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's exactly what it says on the tin: styles should be an array of strings. Instead of

```
    {
    "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
    },
    "src/styles.css"
```

do

```
    "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
    "src/styles.css"
```

Comment: No, still getting the same issue.

Comment: Did you restart `ng serve`?

Comment: Yes, i did still getting the same issue

Comment: And did you fix all `styles` entries? You can have more than one in the `angular.json`

Comment: i have only single angular.json

Comment: There's only one `angular.json`, but it can have several `styles` entries

Comment: Yes there are 2 entries, i replaced at 2 places

Answer (score 0):

In the styles array, you have array of objects with key "input",

It should be a simple **array of strings**

Try like this:

```
"styles": [
   "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
   "src/styles.css"
 ],
 "scripts": [],
```

and prefix the file names with `./` incomponent decorator like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```